# Warning: Task "python_packages" not found. Use --force to continue

Tags: node.js, python-2.7, gruntjs

I am trying to manually setup [this](https://github.com/nasa-gibs/worldview/blob/master/doc/manual_setup.md) project.

When I run `grunt` command, I am getting below error.

> C:\myworkspace\NASA\worldview>grunt
>   Warning: Task "python_packages" not found. Use --force to continue.
>
> Aborted due to warnings.

Tried with `grunt --force`. But not worked.

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

> Use --force to continue.

Try to run `grunt --force`.
If it's only a warning, it should pass.

Comment: Maybe you mistook something. You should post your gruntfile.

Comment: Here is [Gruntfile](https://github.com/nasa-gibs/worldview/blob/master/Gruntfile.js)

Comment: This: grunt.registerTask("default", ["python_packages", "update", "build", "config", "site"]);

Comment: Yeah. What is the issue with this line? Sorry, this is the first time I'm working with grunt.

Comment: I've made some research in Google. Probably there should be a space instead of _. Try to replace it and grunt then.

Comment: No luck. Now getting `Warning: Task "python packages" not found.`

Comment: So you have to check, that python is fully installed with all the things it needs. What do you get when you try to use --force?

Comment: When use `--force`, get `Done, but with warnings.` But `dist` directory is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Delete `python_packages` from line no. 717 of the `Gruntfile.js` and replace it with `exec:python_packages`. So it reads:

```js
grunt.registerTask("default", ["exec:python_packages", "update", "build", "config", "site"]);
```

Then run `$ grunt` via the CLI again.

When the tasks have completed you'll find the `.tar` files in the `dist` folder.

---

**EDIT:**

As per *@Ryuu Agamaki* answer you need to also:

> Change line #321 to
>
> `command: 'virtualenv python && "python/Scripts/pip" install xmltodict isodate'`

`python/bin/` doesn't exist on Windows.

---

**Extracting the `tar.bz2` files**

> This done 99% without errors. But stuck at last minute. Here is the log file

The issue is now related to extracting the `tar.bz2` files. So the commands on line no.s [330](https://github.com/nasa-gibs/worldview/blob/master/Gruntfile.js#L330), [335](https://github.com/nasa-gibs/worldview/blob/master/Gruntfile.js#L335), [340](https://github.com/nasa-gibs/worldview/blob/master/Gruntfile.js#L340), [345](https://github.com/nasa-gibs/worldview/blob/master/Gruntfile.js#L345), [350](https://github.com/nasa-gibs/worldview/blob/master/Gruntfile.js#L350) of the `Gruntfile.js` will all fail on your system. Your [log](http://pastebin.com/wrAJtnUd) on line #103 reports:

`tar: invalid option -- j`

**What are those commands doing?**

As documented [here](https://ss64.com/bash/tar.html), the `cjCf` arguments in the command(s) are:

**`-c`**  : Create a new archive (or truncate an old one) and write the named files to it.

**`-j`**  : filter the archive through bzip2

**`-C`**  : change to directory DIR

**`-f`**  : use archive file or device ARCHIVE

As per your error log it indicates that your system cannot handle the arguments, particularly the `j` argument *(bzip2)*.

**What next?**

I would consider replacing those commands in the `Gruntfile.js` with an equivalent `tar` command that you know works on your system *(Windows)*.

Some tools for handling `tar.bz2` are listed [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/How_to_unpack_a_tar_file_in_Windows) - assuming you don't already have the necessary tool. Whether these offer equivalent commands to handle the `cjCf` arguments I'm not sure. There's also [node-uncompress](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-uncompress) which has command-line commands - which may be worth trying, however, I'm unsure whether it supports cross platform..

The worst case scenario is you may find you have to and omit the calls to the commands, *(i.e. those calls to the lines of code previously mentioned, `"exec:python_packages"` etc, etc)*, from the `Gruntfile.js` completely. Then manually extract the `tar.bz2` files yourself (using something like [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org) or [WinRAR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinRAR)), and move the resultant files into the appropriate folder.

Clearly non *Nix* systems weren't considered/tested when developing the tooling for this project.

Answer (score 0):

Try making these changes in Gruntfile.js

Change line #321 to

```
command: 'virtualenv python && "python/Scripts/pip" install xmltodict isodate'
```

Change line #717 to

```
grunt.registerTask("default", ["exec:python_packages", "update", "build", "config", "site"]);
```

Comment: This done 99% without errors. But stuck at last minute. Here is the [log](http://pastebin.com/wrAJtnUd) file.